# Can't Resolve NPM Dependencies in Shared Angular 2 Library

Tags: angular, npm, graphql, apollo

I am trying to create an Angular 2 library for services, components, and models I want to share between 3-4 different interfaces/apps that are frontends to the same database.

I am using the very helpful Angular 2 generator library [here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library).

My services in the library are based around Apollo client and GraphQL.

However, when I symlink the library build to import into my main project, the Apollo dependencies don't seem to resolve.

I get the following two errors from my app build: `Can't resolve 'apollo-angular/index'` and `Can't resolve 'graphql-tag/index'`. This is in spite of the fact that both these libraries are installed to my `node_modules` in my app, however, they don't seem to transferred by the Gulp build into my `dist` directory of my library but I am not even sure they are meant to be.

I have also tried to setup peer dependencies in my library's `package.json` as follows:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.4.2",
    "apollo-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "apollo-client": "~1.9.0-1"
}
```

In addition, when I run `npm install` to check everything is installed, I get `npm WARN apollo-angular@0.13.0 requires a peer of apollo-client@>=0.8.0 <=0.10.1 || >=1.0.0-rc <2.0.0 but none was installed.` and `npm WARN apollo-client-rxjs@0.5.2 requires a peer of apollo-client@>=0.7.2 <=0.10.1 || >=1.0.0-beta <2.0.0 but none was installed.` even though Apollo Client `1.9.0-1` is installed. I get these warnings for both my app and my library running `npm install`.

If I use Apollo Client in my app directly (not through a library) it works fine in spite of these warnings.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to resolve these issues?

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments, I can confirm that Apollo Client exists in both my app's `node_modules` folder and my library's. The version is `1.9.0-1` in both cases. Apollo Client is used for easily making GraphQL queries from Angular 2 applications.

Comment: not sure what Apollo Client does.. Did you perhaps install it globally, as well as  at the project level perhaps? And a global version is outside the permitted range (<0.8.0 || 2.0.0+). Perhaps that is somehow being seen over a project version. Check your node_modules folder to see what version if any is at project level from npm install too and add that feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might occur because of [this](https://github.com/angular/tsickle/issues/376) issue.

Try to define paths in your ts

```
"compilerOptions" : {

  ...

  "paths": {
    "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
    "apollo-client": ["../node_modules/apollo-client"],
    "apollo-client-rxjs": ["../node_modules/apollo-angular/node_modules/apollo-client-rxjs"]
  }
}
```